# How do I double screw corner posts

Tags: wood, framing

I'm building a dog house for our new puppy and got stuck on something.

The plan...
I want to build a frame and put external and internal walls so I can fill with insulation as Winter where we live gets a bit cold. (around 0-2 during the night).

I had some framing timber hang around in the garage so I'm using that for the frame. Some 45x45 posts and treated ply for the walls and floor.

The problem I found is...
I need to put a couple of screws through the posts into the beans but because the posts are corners posts, I will have 4 screws coming in. Kind of like this (below).

[image]

The problem i find here is that screws will clash to each other. So I was thinking I could divide the bean in for parts (let's say 1,2,3,4) and in one side I would screw the 1 and 3 and the other side I would screw 2 and 4.

Is there the way to do it or there is a better way?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Even if screws touch they usually pass each other, you could just angle them if you are concerned about that.

Comment: Angling them might be tricky... The framing timber is a 45x70 (I believe) so I don't have a lot of space to play...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ed Beal is right. Assuming something like #10 or #12 screws (as opposed to 3/8" lag screws, for example), even if they collide the second will merely glance off the first. It's not an issue.

To avoid the situation altogether, simply offset by 1/4" or so.

Comment: I end up just screwing the second side a tad below. I just wasn't sure if one hits the other, it would bust the wood or something. It's now looking nice and solid. :D

Answer (score 1):

When you drive the first screws, drive at 1 times your measure and 2 times your measure. Turn the corner and drive at 1 1/2 and 2 1/2 your measure of your measure. (Pick your measure to fit your space). For example if you have a five inch space to fasten, screw first 1 and 3 inches from the bottom, turn the corner and screw 2 and 4 inches from the bottom